# with headset connected through Bluetooth, Internet (wifi) keep on disconnecting randomly 16.04

Tags: sound, internet, bluetooth

Normally Wifi works fine but when I connects headset through Bluetooth, than internet (wifi) keep on disconnecting randomly, normally after each 2 minutes to an hour or so.

When wifi disconnects, some times it auto reconnects and some sometimes I have to use

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

one to multiple times to reconnect.

and the in process of internet connect/disconnect, voice in headset breaks (like in pauses) or headset disconnects too.

If I turn off either of wifi or Bluetooth, other one works fine.

Why this is happening and soln ?

response of following command as asked
**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb**

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b52d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: what wifi card do you have?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I don't know, How can I check this ?

Comment: I am afraid there is no solution for this chip. Broadcom drivers badly support bt_coex.

Comment: This a poor proprietary driver released by Broadcom or a hardware limitation. It is impossible to tell. BT and WiFi share the same radio frequency at 2.4. Better adapters can handle it.

Comment: it is possible, better drivers can be found. but it is a trial and error search.

Comment: There is no any other "better" drivers for this chip.

Comment: an alternative is get a bluetooth dongle for the usb. putting the bluetooth and wifi on separate devices should allow both to work

Comment: broadcom provides a linux driver: https://www.broadcom.com/support/download-search/?pg=Wireless+Embedded+Solutions+and+RF+Components&pf=Wireless+LAN/Bluetooth+Combo&pn=&po=&pa=Driver&dk=

Comment: It is already installed ;-)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 https://pastebin.com/TBpbzcYZ